# WSAEWOULDBLOCK handling

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, c++-cli, winsock

I have written a socket for a server in C++ CLI that is using winsock. The sockets are using async methods for sending, receiving and accepting connections. After implementing my socket in the production environment, the send function stops working giving me the error WSAEWOULDBLOCK. Out from my research on the net, this means the network buffer for socket IO is full or the networking is too busy to do my operation at this moment. However, I have not seen any specific solution which can address this problem. My temporary solution was to create a do-while loop around the WSASend function, making the thread sleep for X amount of MS and then try again. This resulted in far higher latency than the previous socket (.NET socket class) and large lag spikes.

My code for sending data is as following:

```
void Connectivity::ConnectionInformation::SendData(unsigned char data[], const int length)
{
    if (isClosed || sendError)
        return;

    Monitor::Enter(this->syncRoot);

    try
    {
        sendInfo->buf = (char*)data;
        sendInfo->len = length;

        do
        {
            state = 0;
            if (WSASend(connection, sendInfo, 1, bytesSent, 0, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                state = WSAGetLastError();
                if (state == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    Thread::Sleep(SleepTime);
                    //Means the networking is busy and we need to wait a bit for data to be sent
                    //Might wanna decrease the value since this could potentially lead to lagg
                }
                else if (state != WSA_IO_PENDING)
                {
                    this->sendError = true;
                    //The send error bool makes sure that the close function doesn't get called
                    //during packet processing which could cause a lot of null reffernce exceptions.
                }
            }
        }
        while (state == WSAEWOULDBLOCK);
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor::Exit(this->syncRoot);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use for example the WSAEventSelect method in order to get a callback when I am able to send data? Out from the documentation on MSDN, the wait for data method could also get stuck in this error. Anyone got any solutions for getting around this?

Comment: What sort of asynchronous operations are you using? Non-blocking sockets or overlapping I/O? What's the general architecture for handling several concurrent requests? Single thread / select / non-blocking sockets? Completion routines? Events?

Comment: It seems you are *not* using async IO. Why do you think you are?

Comment: I thought the WSASend method was async by default. The send method is a send-and-forget method since I don't care much about the result of the callback. I am using the .NET thread pool for waiting for callback on the receive and connection accepting:
 WaitHandle ^ handle = gcnew ManualResetEvent(false);
 IntPtr handlePointer = handle->SafeWaitHandle->DangerousGetHandle();

 WSAEventSelect(listener, (void*)handlePointer, FD_ACCEPT);
 ThreadPool::UnsafeRegisterWaitForSingleObject(handle, callback, nullptr, -1, true);
How do I know if I'm using non-blocking, overlapped IO or blocking sockets?

Comment: Please append to code to your question. It's hardly readable in the comment.

Comment: MSDN has an example for [Asynchronous Server Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.100).aspx). It's much easier since it's .NET only (no C++, C++ CLI). An alternative would be to use several threads and go for simple blocking I/O (in C# only).

Comment: I want to use the winsock directly since the socket class in .net caused a lot of object generation which had a negative impact on the performance of my application.

Comment: I somewhat doubt that a .NET solution is too inefficient unless you have 10,000s of concurrent connections. If it's less than 10k connections, stay with a pure .NET solution and isolate your bottleneck. It won't be the .NET socket classes. If it's more than 10k connections, then you'll need to invest a lot of time in learning Windows socket functions, fundamentals of asynchronous communication in Windows etc. and you'll need to a lot of time for writing and testing robust and scalable code.

Comment: Ar 6.000 connections I get a large amount of object creation from the socket, when the GC kicks in I get huge lag spikes. Thats why I decided to use Winsock.

Comment: How do you know the object creation is from the socket communication and not from the core work your server is supposed to? I guess your server does more than just communication.

Comment: What communication model did you use in your C# solution? One thread per connection? Asynchronous communication by using the BeginXXX / EndXXX methods? Or completion ports?

Comment: Im currently using async sockets. I know the object creation is by the socket by memory profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @usr says, I need to have either LPWSAOVERLAPPED or LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE set to a value in order to make the operation non-blocking. However, after testing, I found out I need t have a LPWSAOVERLAPPED object in order to make the completion routine called. It is also mentioned on MSDN on the documentation of the WSASend function that if the overlapped object and the completion routine is NULL, the socket would behave as a blocking socket.

Thanks, and merry xmas everyone! :)

Answer (score 3):

The error code `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` means that you attempted to operate on a non-blocking socket but the operation could not be completed immediately. This is not a real error - it means that you can retry later or schedule an asynchronous IO (which wouldn't fail). But this is not what you want in the first place. Let me explain:

You are supposed to use sockets in one of two ways:

1. Synchronous, blocking.
2. Asynchronous, non-blocking, callback-based.

You are mixing the two which gets you the worst of both. You created a non-blocking socket and use it in a potentially blocking way.

Alas I'm not full qualified to give best-practices for native-code sockets. I suggest you read all of the [docs for WSASend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because they seem to explain all of this.

Now, why would this strange error code even exist? It is a performance optimization. You can speculatively try to send synchronously (which is very fast). And only if it fails you are supposed to schedule an asynchronous IO. If you don't need that optimization (which you don't) don't do it.

Comment: My socket is working in 90% of the send operations, out from what I understand on what I have read around the net, I would get that error on all send operations when the sockets are initially blocking. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx says "This error is returned from operations on nonblocking sockets that cannot be completed immediately, for example recv when no data is queued to be read from the socket" I know I need to try again, I just need an event or something that tells me when I am able to send data as I explained in my first post.

Comment: @Martin, as I explained, WSASend in non-blocking mode *can* be successful iff the data can be queued into the send-queue in memory. If the queue is full the call fails. The text you just quoted says a similar thing for recv (do you agree?).; What do you think of my recommendation to stick with (1) or (2)? Currently, you are not using sockets the way they are supposed to be used. If you do it right, you don't need an event. You just need to call WSASend and it won't ever fail.

Comment: So out from what I see, I need to call ioctlsocket to set the socket to async mode. Am I supposed to call this method after accepting the connection and are there any other parameters I should add in it instead of a null pointer? Also, I would like to stick with non-blocking/async sockets.

Comment: @Martin, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203(v=vs.85).aspx you are supposed to create the socket as overlapped (which is different from non-blocking!) and use WSASend with at least one of an overlapped structure or a completion callback (I recommend the latter). Note, that you are not supposed to wait on anything - rely only on the callback. This will force your code to be turned inside out so that it is callback-based. Maybe you can switch to sync IO (why can't you?).