# TCP socket on Linux(ubuntu) mono makes error

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ubuntu, mono

I'm currently have a test project made up with C#. Basically it makes a TCP Listener socket. but it makes an error if i try to accept connection.

```
socket_tcpListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket_tcpListener.Bind(endPoint);
socket_tcpListener.Listen(28);
socket_tcpListener.Accept();
```

above code is exactly what i've done. it was completely fine when i ran this compiled .exe on window. an it was also find when i've ran this project without compile using 'dotnet run' command.
but if i compile the project to .dll file using 'dotnet msbuild' command and run with 'dotnet run' command, it make errors.

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Operation on non-blocking socket would block

I've logged each line to find out exact position making error. so i found Accept method in last line occurs error.

disable blocking(socket.Blocking = false) didn't help. and the  I don't really know why, only compiled dll make error. need help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010285/wsaewouldblock-handling. Without a [mcve], there's no way to know what you did wrong. I am _very_ skeptical that the code you posted is literally all that's required. If Mono were by default making every `Socket` object non-blocking, we'd have hundreds of questions similar to yours here. However, if the code you posted is literally all that's needed, I suggest you listen on a different port #. 28 is in the "well-known" range, but is not assigned to anything useful, so you likely shouldn't be using it. Maybe Ubuntu and/or Mono treats it uniquely.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thank you for the comment! I've re-written the code to use Asyn methods and it worked! the first link was very helpful.

Comment: BTW, try to use .NET Core instead of Mono, which is more consistent on multiple platforms.